# Can someone explain the best way to reformat the output of awk () | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg?

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, printf, uniq

I have made a script for analyzing Windows logs message numbers. The output of the uniq -c numbers are difficult to predict, because there is varying white-space depending on the size of the numbers. At this point I remove white-space manually.

This is the command which sorts and counts the messages:

```
cat nt2.rawlog | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print $3,$4,$6,$7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg >> ~/tempNT2.report
```

This is my best attempt at an example output:

```
21340  4624,Windows-Security-Audit-Log,Success Audit,Logon
 1209  4658,Windows-Security-Audit-Log,Success Audit,Privileged Logon
```

My desired output is:

```
[tab]21340[tab]--[tab]Security Audit Log 4624 (Logon Success Audit)
[tab]1209[tab]--[tab]Security Audit Log 4658 (Privileged Logon Success Audit)
```

Comment: As an aside, dumping a question here and then leaving is not really good form.  Very often, you will receive requests for clarification soon after posting, especially when it's your first time here (although this question in fact seems to contain all the necessary information -- good job!)

Comment: Of course, the [`cat` is useless](http://iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am new to this. I have been looking for ways to speed up scripts. Would these be the proper cat-less set of commands?

Comment: `awk -F , '{print $3,$4,$6,$7}' nt2.rawlog | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg >> ~/tempNT2.report `

Comment: `awk -F , '{ i = split($1, n, / +/); printf ("\t%d\t--\t%s %d (%s %s)\n", n[i-1], $2, n[i], substr($4, 2), $3) }' ~/tempNT2.report`

Comment: Yeah, that looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
awk -F , '{ i = split($1, n, / +/);
  printf ("\t%d\t--\t%s %d (%s %s)\n", n[i-1], $2, n[i], substr($4, 2), $3) }'
```

The field separator `,` does the first level of splitting; then we split the first field on whitespace, and extract the numbers into `n`.  The number of elements in `n` depends on whether the field had leading whitespace or not, so we count the last two fields from the end.  The last field has a pesky leading space, so we extract a substring from the second character of that field.

Comment: Have not yet tested the command but that leading space in the last field likely is not there. Will the command end like this:...$2, n[i], $4, $3) }'

Comment: Yeah, just take out the substr if that part is not desired.